# Undefined Reference to RasDialA (with ras.h included)

Tags: c, windows, header-files, vpn, ras

I read all of Microsoft's documentation but their claim is that it should work without any additional libs. An hour of Googling yielded no results. My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ras.h>

int main()
{
    char* szPhoneNumberToDial = "127.0.0.1";
    char* szUserName = "test";
    char* szPassword = "test";
    RASDIALPARAMS rdParams;
    rdParams.dwSize = sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS);
    rdParams.szEntryName[0] = '\0';
    lstrcpy(rdParams.szPhoneNumber, szPhoneNumberToDial);
    rdParams.szCallbackNumber[0] = '\0';
    lstrcpy( rdParams.szUserName, szUserName );
    lstrcpy( rdParams.szPassword, szPassword );
    rdParams.szDomain[0] = '\0';

    HRASCONN hRasConn = NULL;
    DWORD dwRet = RasDial(NULL, NULL, &rdParams, 0L, NULL, &hRasConn);
}
```

Error:

`undefined reference to 'RasDialA@24'`

I tried both a C and C++ implementation (in both VC++ 2010 and MinGW/gcc & g++) but they both resulted in this same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`according documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),  the requirements to [`RasDial()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) usage, also `Ras.h` 
header, is the `Rasapi32.lib` library. If this is avaliable on your compiler, pass it to link by using [`-l`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) option on

**gcc**:

```
gcc foo.c -lRasapi32
```

*EDIT:* Thanks to @Mark Wilkins, that has provided the command-line for

**Microsoft Compiler**:

```
cl foo.c rasapi32.lib
```

Comment: +1 (or if using the Microsoft compiler, it would be:  cl foo.c rasapi32.lib).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry I didn't catch that bit, I thought `rasapi32.lib` was inherent to the `ras.h` but I was wrong.